# Building OpenCV-DNN module for 32-Bit UWP?

Tags: visual-studio, opencv, cmake, linker

is it possible to build the OpenCV-DNN module for 32-Bit UWP? I cloned the official OpenCV repository and generated the VS-Projectfiles with the Generator "Visual Studio 14 2015" and set the flags -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=WindowsStore -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=10.0. However building for UWP will cause the dnn-module to not be included, so I changed the cmake files to include the module and I was able to build the binaries with Visual Studio.

Now here is the problem:
When I create a C++ UWP-Application, link the opencv_dnn.lib file, consume it and launch my app, I get the error:

```
"Unable to activate Windows Store app MYAPP. The MYAPP.exe
process started, but the activation request failed with error 'The app
didn't start'."
```

This happens for the debug and release configuration. If I link it, but don't use it at all in my code, I do not get the error. I looked the error up, but was not able to fix it.

Since the unmodified cmakefiles provided in the repo exclude the dnn-module when targeting UWP, I tought, that it is not possible to build this specific module.

Does anyone why this error would occur or if it is possible to build it with UWP as target? I did find [this](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/9177) , which suggests that it is possible, although there bugs (not related to linking).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so i figured it out. I did get the same error for every other opncv module. The problem was that Visual Studio didn't find the opencv dlls despite them being listed under the PATH env variable. I added the dlls to my project folder and was able to launch my program and use opencv.